# Compatability of Haskell heap and deepseq library

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to make some code that uses the heap-1.0.0 package from hackage use deepseq to ensure that a calculation is fully strictly evaluated.

I've found that to use deepseq I need to declare NFData instances for the types involved in the larger expression. All good so far. Then I get to the Data.Heap that I use to hold a priority queue of some items. Suddenly not so good.

Essentially, as far as I can tell, I can't make deepseq and heap work together because the data constructors for heap are hidden away, and NFData instances are not declared inside the heap library itself.

Is my understanding correct? Are there any known ways of making these libraries work together and interoperate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about polling the maintainers to add the required instances?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to deepseq a heap.  The HeapT type is defined as

```
data HeapT prio val
    = Empty  -- ^ An empty 'HeapT'.
    | Tree { _rank     :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int -- ^ Rank of the leftist heap.
           , _size     :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int -- ^ Number of elements in the heap.
           , _priority :: !prio               -- ^ Priority of the entry.
           , _value    :: val                 -- ^ Value of the entry.
           , _left     :: !(HeapT prio val)   -- ^ Left subtree.
           , _right    :: !(HeapT prio val)   -- ^ Right subtree.
           } -- ^ A tree node of a non-empty 'HeapT'.
    deriving (Typeable)
```

If you just use a normal `seq`, it will evaluate a Heap to weak-head normal form, i.e. either the `Empty` or `Tree` constructor.  Since the size field is strict, this will fully evaluate the spine of the heap.

If you combine this with `deepseq`ing new items as you enter them, the heap will be fully evaluated.

```
let insert' item heap = item `deepseq` Data.Heap.insert item heap

let newheap = insert' item heap
in newheap `seq` do_something_else
```

That being said, I wouldn't be surprised if this leads to worse performance.  Since the heap package uses Okasaki's implementation, it relies on laziness for certain performance guarantees.  Try it and see.

Comment: My understanding is that Okasaki's laziness techniques are mostly to hide housekeeping activities like tree balancing behind thunks, to give *persistent* structures the same amortized performance characteristics a *linear* version would have. So if the entire heap is used in a completely sequential way, we have merely useless *procrastination*, not beneficial *laziness*. :]

Comment: The idea of rnfing tends to be that you really have a lazy data structure that you use lazily. Then, every now and then, you force that it is fully evaluated for one or another reason (perhaps to ensure it is exception free before passing it to a particularly fiddly function, or perhaps to ensure that the "work" it represents is done before it is passed from a worker thread back to a main thread) -- using a data structure strictly is generally an entirely different issue...

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like I'm just trying to do the wrong here. After further investigation, it looks like my problem lies elsewhere and my apparent need for a heap deepseq was a red herring. Thanks for the replies though - this really helps my understanding! :-)

Comment: @user935572: are you using the heap profiler?  It can often help with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
instance NFData Heap where
       rnf x = rnf (toUnsortedList x) `seq` ()
```

Not the most efficient, but then rnfing everything willy nilly usually isn't :-)